# Win32 API C++ Hwnd Returning Null

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I've got a simple WIN3API application,
It was working completely at first, when I decided to do a code clean-up by adding comments and spaces to make the code more readable due for myself so I could easily add more functionality, next thing I know the code does not work. When the main function runs the 'Mainhwnd' returns 'NULL' and closes, I assumed that it might've been the class registering although it does not seem to be the problem, any help would be utmost appreciated! Thanks,
Here's a code snippet:

```
int main(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const wchar_t MainWndClass[] = L"MainWndClass";       // Creating And Registering Main Class
    WNDCLASS MainClass = { };
    MainClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    MainClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    MainClass.lpszClassName = MainWndClass;
    if (!RegisterClass(&MainClass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error Registering Window Class", L"Error Registering Window", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }
Mainhwnd = CreateWindowEx
    (
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        MainWndClass,                   // Window class
        L"Main Wnd",                    // Window text
        WS_VISIBLE,                     // Window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                  // XPos
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                  // YPos
        MainWindWidth,                  // Width
        MainWindHeight,                 // Height
        NULL,                           // Parent window    
        NULL,                           // Menu
        hInstance,                      // Instance handle
        NULL                            // Additional application data
    );
    if (Mainhwnd == NULL)               // Quit If Error
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error Creating Window; Window Handle Is NULL", L"Error Creating Window", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }
```

Full Code

```
// Includes

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

// Definitions

#define BUTTON_ONE_ID 0001
#define BUTTON_TWO_ID 0002
#define BUTTON_THREE_ID 0003
#define BUTTON_FOUR_ID 0004
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

// Global Variables

HWND Mainhwnd;
HMENU hMenu;
HWND ButtonOne;
HWND ButtonTwo;
HWND ButtonThree;
HWND ButtonFour;
INT MainWindWidth = 800;
INT MainWindHeight = 600;
INT ButtonWidth = MainWindWidth/4;
INT ButtonHeight = 100;

// Prototypes

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void AddMenus(HWND);
void AddControls(HWND);

// Entry Point

int main(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const wchar_t MainWndClass[] = L"MainWndClass";       // Creating And Registering Main Class
    WNDCLASS MainClass = { };
    MainClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    MainClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    MainClass.lpszClassName = MainWndClass;
    if (!RegisterClass(&MainClass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error Registering Window Class", L"Error Registering Window", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }
    Mainhwnd = CreateWindowEx
    (
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        MainWndClass,                   // Window class
        L"Main Wnd",                    // Window text
        WS_VISIBLE,                     // Window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                  // XPos
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                  // YPos
        MainWindWidth,                  // Width
        MainWindHeight,                 // Height
        NULL,                           // Parent window    
        NULL,                           // Menu
        hInstance,                      // Instance handle
        NULL                            // Additional application data
    );
    if (Mainhwnd == NULL)               // Quit If Error
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error Creating Window; Window Handle Is NULL", L"Error Creating Window", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }
    ShowWindow(Mainhwnd, nCmdShow);     // Show Window
    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

// Create Window Procedure

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case BUTTON_ONE_ID:
            std::cout << "B1" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        case BUTTON_TWO_ID:
            std::cout << "B2" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        case BUTTON_THREE_ID:
            std::cout << "B3" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        case BUTTON_FOUR_ID:
            std::cout << "B4" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenus(hwnd);
        AddControls(hwnd);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 2));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    default:
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
void AddMenus(HWND hwnd)                    // Add Menus Function
{
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();
    SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);
}
void AddControls(HWND hwnd)                 // Add Controls Function
{
    ButtonOne = CreateWindowW
    (
        L"Button", L"Button1", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 0, 475, ButtonWidth, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_ONE_ID, NULL, NULL
    );
    ButtonTwo = CreateWindowW
    (
        L"Button", L"Button2", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, ButtonWidth, 475, ButtonWidth, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_TWO_ID, NULL, NULL
    );
    ButtonThree = CreateWindowW
    (
        L"Button", L"Button3", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, ButtonWidth * 2, 475, ButtonWidth, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_THREE_ID, NULL, NULL
    );
    ButtonFour = CreateWindowW
    (
        L"Button", L"Button4", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, ButtonWidth * 3, 475, ButtonWidth, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_FOUR_ID, NULL, NULL
    );
}
```

Comment: Don't you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: First thing to do is read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa). It says "If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

Comment: `default: return 0;` is the bug.  It prevents DefWindowProc() from being called.  So WM_NCCREATE does not get handled.  No error either, you explicitly said you handled it yourself.  Just delete it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why CreateWindowEx() return NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213478/why-createwindowex-return-null)

Comment: @ray Not quite. They both fall into the *"I didn't expect that"* bucket, but have different root causes. The referenced Q&A talks about the observable effects of  undefined behavior. This question is about unexpected observable effects of well defined behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable They both come down to failing to end with `return DefWindowProc` for unhandled messages, hence the proposed duplicate.

Comment: FWIW changing the definition of `UNICODE` after `#define <windows.h>` is a really bad idea...

Comment: @ray That's undoubtedly correct., from a 30'000 ft high view. Depending on where you draw the line, this could be seen as a duplicate of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27213478/1889329). I will still argue that it rather involves already knowing the answer to the problem to derive the solution of *"removing a `return` statement"* from an answer that suggests to *"add a `return` keyword"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outcome of calling [CreateWindowExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw) falls into one of three categories: "Failure", "cancellation", or "success". The following table lists those categories based on the function's return value, and the return value of [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror):

| Return value | `GetLastError` | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `NULL` | non-zero | Window creation failed due to an error |
| `NULL` | zero | Window creation was cancelled by client code |
| non-`NULL` | *<indeterminate>* | Window creation succeeded |

Since it isn't relevant to the discussion here, let's get the final row out of the way: The function call returned a non-`NULL` value, singalling successful window creation. The return value of `GetLastError` is meaningless in this case, and can literally be any value.

The first row marks a true error condition. The window creation request couldn't be satisfied, either due to a programming error (e.g. passing in an invalid window class, window handle, ...) or an environmental issue like resource exhaustion.

The second row in the table above is the one that frequently causes confusion. Window creation didn't happen, but there's no error reported either. Wait, what? How can this fail without an error!?

It is failing *on request*!

Unintuitive as it may appear, the window procedure responsible for the behavior of an instance of a window class is already involved in the process of creating that instance. There are two<sup>1</sup> window messages sent to the window procedure associated with a window class during window construction. Either one can abandon the request prematurely<sup>2</sup>: `WM_NCCREATE` and `WM_CREATE`.

The semantics of [`WM_CREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create#return-value)'s return value include the following:

> If the application returns -1, the window is destroyed and the `CreateWindowEx` or `CreateWindow` function returns a `NULL` handle.

Prior to that, a [`WM_NCCREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccreate) message is sent. The semantics of its return value are documented as well:

> If the application returns `FALSE`, the [`CreateWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowa) or [`CreateWindowEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa) function will return a NULL handle.

That's all the information needed to answer the question:

```cpp
default:
    return 0;
```

This returns 0 (which is interpreted as `FALSE`) for any unhandled message, including `WM_NCCREATE`. Since there is no explicit message handler for the `WM_NCCREATE` message that's what the window procedure returns, thereby terminating the request to create the window.

To fix this<sup>3</sup> you would either need to add default processing to the `default:` label, i.e.

```cpp
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

and remove the trailing return statement<sup>4</sup>, or remove the `default` label altogether.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Future visitors may find this to be inaccurate. Sorry, I don't have access to a time machine.*

<sup>2</sup> *Literally.*

<sup>3</sup> *[Your compiler probably warned you about this](https://godbolt.org/z/1evnrnY6j).*

<sup>4</sup> *Make sure to fix the (possibly unintended) `WM_PAINT` fall-through into `default` along the way.*

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Working Code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case BUTTON_ONE_ID:
            std::cout << "B1" << std::endl;
            break;
        case BUTTON_TWO_ID:
            std::cout << "B2" << std::endl;
            break;
        case BUTTON_THREE_ID:
            std::cout << "B3" << std::endl;
            break;
        case BUTTON_FOUR_ID:
            std::cout << "B4" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenus(hwnd);
        AddControls(hwnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 2));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
void AddMenus(HWND hwnd)                    // Add Menus Function
{
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();
    SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);
}
void AddControls(HWND hwnd)                 // Add Controls Function
{
    
    ButtonOne = CreateWindowW
    (
        L"Button", L"Button1", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 0, 475, ButtonWidth, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_ONE_ID, NULL, NULL
    );
    ButtonTwo = CreateWindowW
    (
        L"Button", L"Button2", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, ButtonWidth, 475, ButtonWidth, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_TWO_ID, NULL, NULL
    );
    ButtonThree = CreateWindowW
    (
        L"Button", L"Button3", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, ButtonWidth * 2, 475, ButtonWidth, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_THREE_ID, NULL, NULL
    );
    ButtonFour = CreateWindowW
    (
        L"Button", L"Button4", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, ButtonWidth * 3, 475, ButtonWidth, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_FOUR_ID, NULL, NULL
    );
}
```

Comment: There's still a fallthrough from the `WM_PAINT` handler. You should be returning 0 instead. Your compiler should have warned you about this as well.

Comment: I see, Visual Studio 2019 has not thrown any sort of issues on runtime or compilation, Thanks